# migrate from JBOSS AS6 to wild fly

Tags: jboss, wildfly, wildfly-8

I know its a very high level question, but it will be very much help full if somebody can help me to kick start the migration.

So please provide some links or use full hints to start with it.
Also if somebody knows about delta changes between JBOSS AS 6 to Wild fly.

Major change which i know that our application uses-

JBOSS AOP
JBOSS Interceptors
and binds it in jboss-aop.xml
like below

```
<bind pointcut="execution(public * *.DBDAO      &gt;updateBO(com.test.model.TestClass,  com.test.model.TestClass2))">
    <interceptor-ref name="TestInterceptor"/>
</bind>
```

which is not supported by wild fly now.

And so there must be other thing s which might not be supported by wild fly.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

According documentation:

> **Replace JBoss AOP Interceptors**
>
> **JBoss AOP (Aspect Oriented Programming)** is no longer included in JBoss AS 7. In previous releases, JBoss AOP was used by the EJB container. However, in AS 7, the EJB container uses a new mechanism. If your application uses **JBoss AOP**, you need modify your application code as follows.
>
> - Standard EJB3 configurations that were made in the `ejb3-interceptors-aop.xml` file are now done in the server configuration file. For a standalone server, this is the `standalone/configuration/standalone.xml` file. If you are running your server in a managed domain, this is the `domain/configuration/domain.xml` file.
> - Applications that integrate AOP interceptors into the EJB layer must be redesigned to use **EJB3 interceptors** and **CDI**. Server side interceptors can be changed to **EJB3 interceptors**, but there is no client side interceptor in AS 7.

Like AOP exist other changes you can see in:  [How do I migrate my application from AS5 or AS6 to WildFly](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY8/How+do+I+migrate+my+application+from+AS5+or+AS6+to+WildFly) and [Experiences with migrating from JBoss AS 7 to WildFly 8.1](http://jdevelopment.nl/experiences-migrating-jboss-7-wildfly-81/)

The last link refers to some changes that are not in the official documentation.

Comment: thnx for it. i will post further if any question(that will be for sure ;).

Answer (score 1):

Here is whole migration guide from Red Hat. JBoss EAP 6.2 has similar architecture to WildFly so you can use it:

https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_Application_Platform/6.2/html-single/Migration_Guide/index.html